# How can I automate Silverlight application with selenium webdriver?

Tags: silverlight, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new with Silverlight and Selenium. I searched to automate my Silverlight application with Selenium webdriver but I didn't find any useful source. Can someone guide me?

Cheers,

Comment: Can't be done! Selenium uses the browser DOM. Silverlight does not exist in the DOM. You will need another tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to declare methods and attributes as `[Scriptable]` or a whole class as `[ScriptableType]`. This way you can invoke/access them via JavaScript, which can be done via WebDriver's `executeScript` and `executeAsyncScript` methods. In the class constructor, you can make the instance visible in the DOM by calling:
    HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("AnyNameYouWant", this);

Note that no default WebDriver interaction (click, typeKeys) will work within your Silverlight object, so a click on a button, for instance, will have to be done programmatically like:

```
var peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(button);
var ip = (IInvokeProvider)peer;
ip.Invoke();
```

The silverlight-selenium project (https://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/) provides some fixtures for common UI components, relying solely on this JavaScript to Silverlight bridge. Unfortunately, this project is not currently active, but the examples should give you some insights.